# How to access MYSQL via Docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm new to the Docker world. I have a NodeJS app that is currently running on a docker container locally. As a next step, I would like to access my AWS Aurora MySQL database from this Nodejs app and expose the data via REST APIs.

Currently, I can access my Aurora MySQL (via workbench) only through a VPN. Given this condition, how can I test the API after hosting in a docker container?

Comment: If you can only access your MySQL remotely via VPN you should update your AWS security to allow access from the IP  the DOCKER app is running on.